# Applying random function(from a couple of them) every time the program starts

Tags: python, function

I created a couple of functions, to change the theme of my application. Some examples are given below:

```
def redtheme():
    text.config(background="light salmon", foreground="red",
            insertbackground="red")

def greentheme():
    text.config(background="pale green", foreground="dark green",
                insertbackground="dark green")

def bluetheme():
    text.config(background="light blue", foreground="dark blue",
                insertbackground="blue")
```

(text is the name of the text widget)

I want to create a function that makes a random one of these functions run whenever the application is started.
In other words, I want a function that is executed when the application starts, the function will choose from `random.choice()`, a function and execute that function:

```
full = (redtheme, greentheme, bluetheme)
selected = random.choice(full)
# here, it could be text.config(full)?? or what?
```

How do I make it so that one of the three functions is executed whenever the application starts

Comment: Just call `selected` before `mainloop`, since it's a random function from the list.

Answer (score 2):

AS also suggested in [CommonSense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6634373/commonsense)'s comment below code is a small example of what you wanted:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)

def redtheme():
    text.config(background="light salmon", foreground="red",
            insertbackground="red")

def greentheme():
    text.config(background="pale green", foreground="dark green",
                insertbackground="dark green")

def bluetheme():
    text.config(background="light blue", foreground="dark blue",
                insertbackground="blue")

full = (redtheme, greentheme, bluetheme)
selected = random.choice(full)

selected()
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The code above basically makes use of the fact that you can assign function references to variables, here random choice in function name references is assigned to `selected` first, then `selected` was called as a function.

---

Additionally see below example for a call right away of a random choice of functions:

```
random.choice((redtheme, greentheme, bluetheme))()
```